# pod failed to get Plugin from volumeSpec for volume in k8s，using gluster?

Tags: kubernetes, volume, glusterfs

**I try to deply pod by use pvc, but error happen.
I can't fix this problem, please help me fix this problem**

pod error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    4m14s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned app-storage-platform/backend-deployment-57bfc697c7-877bf to 10.30.48.110
  Warning  FailedMount  4m14s               kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[glusterfs-testplatform-pv kube-api-access-pbz29], unattached volumes=[], failed to process volumes=[glusterfs-testplatform-pv]: failed to get Plugin from volumeSpec for volume "glusterfs-testplatform-pv" err=no volume plugin matched
  Warning  FailedMount  0s (x19 over 4m2s)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[glusterfs-testplatform-pv], unattached volumes=[], failed to process volumes=[glusterfs-testplatform-pv]: failed to get Plugin from volumeSpec for volume "glusterfs-testplatform-pv" err=no volume plugin matched
```

```
[root@centos-68 storage]# kubectl get pv -n app-storage-platform
NAME                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                             STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
glusterfs-testplatform-pv   1000Gi     RWX            Delete           Bound    app-storage-platform/glusterfs-testplatform-pvc                           10m
[root@centos-68 storage]# kubectl describe pv -n app-storage-platform
Name:            glusterfs-testplatform-pv
Labels:          pv=glusterfs-testplatform-pv
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    
Status:          Bound
Claim:           app-storage-platform/glusterfs-testplatform-pvc
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWX
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        1000Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:                Glusterfs (a Glusterfs mount on the host that shares a pod's lifetime)
    EndpointsName:       glusterfs-cluster
    EndpointsNamespace:  <unset>
    Path:                gfsvolume_k8s
    ReadOnly:            false
Events:                  <none>
```

```
[root@centos-68 storage]# kubectl describepvc -n app-storage-platform                                                                                 
error: unknown command "describepvc" for "kubectl"
[root@centos-68 storage]# kubectl describe pvc -n app-storage-platform                                                                                
Name:          glusterfs-testplatform-pvc
Namespace:     app-storage-platform
StorageClass:  
Status:        Bound
Volume:        glusterfs-testplatform-pv
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      1000Gi
Access Modes:  RWX
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       backend-deployment-57bfc697c7-877bf
Events:        <none>
[root@centos-68 storage]# 
[root@centos-68 storage]# kubectl get pvc -n app-storage-platform                                                                                     
NAME                         STATUS   VOLUME                      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
glusterfs-testplatform-pvc   Bound    glusterfs-testplatform-pv   1000Gi     RWX                           9m35s
```

this is config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0sbI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tXIQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Pd3.png)

I look forward to fixing this issue and pointing out what is the cause of the error